# Exact cover matrix for project planning

Tags: combinatorics

I'm trying to solve the project planning problem using [DLX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_Algorithm_X) and exact cover matrix, but I'm struggling to find the set of constraints (columns) and the set of options (rows) to achieve this. Here is a sample that represents the main constraints of the problem.

- Each project have a set of tasks $\{T_1, T_2, T_3\}$
- Each project have a set of resources $\{R_1, R_2\}$
- Each task has a duration ($T_1$ has $2$ days, $T_2$ has $3$ days, $T_3$ has $4$ days)
- Tasks can block each other, and tasks can be blocked by $0$ or many other tasks ($T_1$ is not blocked, $T_2$ is blocked by $T_1$, $T_3$ is blocked by $T_1$ and $T_2$)
- Only one resource can work on task at a time
- Resource can only work on one task at a time

I tried several combinations but none of them worked for me. I'm using this [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dance) package to test the matrix.

Can anyone help me find the right set of constraints and options to feed the matrix.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Does each task require both the resources to completes its execution? or any one of the resources? Are the resources identical in the time they finish executing a task? What  is the objective? Do you want a feasible assignment of tasks to resources? or you also want to complete all the tasks in minimum duration?

Comment: @InuyashaYagami thank you for your comment. Here are some more details. Each task should be executed by only one ressource (any of the ressource). For my first iteration, it is ok to consider that all ressources are identical. The goal is to find all scenarios that complete all the tasks

Comment: Since there are only $3$ tasks why not do this by enumerating all possibilities?

Comment: The project in the description is just a sample. Real world scenario will involves more tasks and more ressources

Answer (score 0):

Your problem fall under deadlock avoidance and can be solved easily by [Bankers algorithm.](https://www-geeksforgeeks-org.cdn.ampproject.org/v/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/deadlock-prevention/amp/?amp_gsa=1&amp_js_v=a9&usqp=mq331AQIUAKwASCAAgM%3D#amp_tf=From%20%251%24s&aoh=16889086058555&referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com&ampshare=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.geeksforgeeks.org%2Fdeadlock-prevention%2F)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i’ll have a look, but I’m looking for a solution using DLX. If you think that this not feasible, please let me know